# How to fix Ubuntu non-latin keyboard shortcuts in JetBrains products (WebStorm, IDEA)?

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

Like most, I ran into the problem of non-working hotkeys (<kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>crtl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>) with a non-Latin keyboard layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On ubuntu 18, I solved this problem.

**I did not have to install additional libraries to fix it!**

All i did is swap the **input source**
So that English was the first. (before it was Russian)

[image: Ubuntu input source]

It was tested on webstorm and intellij idea

Comment: The problem is that java returns incorrect key codes unless US keyboard layout is default and the first in the list.
We have fixed it in our custom OSX JRE, fixes for Windows (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-216) and Linux (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-215) are in progress